# Playback sound is being captured

Tags: linux, arch-linux, alsa, pulse-audio

I've been having issues my audio. When I capture audio, I am capturing playback audio unless I specify the correct device (see below).
So instead of my usb microphone being captured, the sound being playback through my headphones is being captured.

I'm unsure what is happening and how to fix it. I am using ALSA and Pulseaudio, and my asound.conf is the default one generated by Pulseaudio. Output of `cat /proc/asound/cards`:

```
0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                     HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7910000 irq 29
1 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                     HDA NVidia at 0xf7080000 irq 17
2 [C01U           ]: USB-Audio - Samson C01U
                     Samson Technologies Samson C01U at usb-0000:00:14.0-9, full speed
```

Output of `amixer -c0 contents`: https://pastebin.com/cyERFpPk

To record sound when testing my mic, I used audacity with the recording device set to `Samson C01U:USB Audio (hw:2,0): Front Mic:0` and I used arecord with `arecord -d 2 -D hw:2,0 -f cd test.wav`. Both record sound from my mic, however when playing the sound back from `arecord`, it only plays through the left of my headphones.

I've also noticed another issue. Overtime (especially when I'm playing around with my audio levels) I start to hear some static when listening to audio. Sometimes it's really faint, and other times it's very loud. This has never happend to me. I can resolve this by restarting pulseaudio, but it is annoying to do so.

My `/etc/asound.conf`: https://pastebin.com/2XSEhfHb. I don't have a `~/.asoundrc`.

Comment: Please add details about your configuration, if you are using ALSA or Pulseaudio, and how exactly you go about capturing sound. The more details, the better; as the question is, it's a guessing game. Potential reasons: Wrong setup for sound capture, or hardware loopback from headphones to capture channel enabled (check with `alsamixer` or `amixer`).

Comment: @dirkt What configuration details do you need? I don't quite understand Pulseaudio or ALSA or their configuration so please excuse me if I am not giving enough infomation.

Comment: Please: (1) Edit question with output of `cat /proc/asound/cards` (2) Identify the card number in the above output that has your headphones, say `42`, save output of `amixer -c42 contents` in a pastebin, and edit question with link. (3) Describe step-by-step what you are doing to record sound ("I am using `audacity`, with the capture device set to XXX" or "I do `arecord -d hw:0 ...`", etc. ).

Comment: To clarify: Your problem is not that *while* you capture sound, you hear something in your headphones. Your problem is that you can capture sound from the Samson just fine, but when you *play it back* through the headphones connected to your Intel soundcard, you just hear it in the left ear, though you'd have expected to hear it in both ears. Is this correct?

Comment: The problem is that by default when I capture audio, I am capturing playback audio unless I specify the correct device. If I use the command `arecord -d 2 test.wav` with out specifying the device, it records playback audio. This is the same with discord, as when I use the voice channels everyone else just hears my playback audio. When I can specify the deivce, it works, but when it uses my default device, it captures my playback audio. I wish to fix this so that my default device is my USB microphone, not my playback audio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my playback audio being recorded by removing pulseaudio

Answer (score 1):

Ok, quick overview how stuff works.

Your Intel HDA soundcard has a digital connection to a "codec" chip, which contains the D/A and A/D converters, analog mixers, analog amplifiers, and analog switches. ALSA has kernel drivers for the soundcards, and assigns the mixer elements you can see in `amixer` to control some (but not all) of the stuff in the codec.

You can configure ALSA with "plugins" through the system-wide `/etc/asound.conf` or the per-users `~/.asoundrc`.

Pulseaudio runs on top of ALSA, and presents an unified audio transport mechanism to applications. It takes care of sampling rate conversion etc., which makes Pulseaudio much more pleasant to use (in principle) than ALSA. The standard configuration is that Pulseaudio presents a compatibility layer to legacy ALSA applications with entries like

```
pcm.!default pulse
ctl.!default pulse
```

These set the default ALSA input and output in such a way that ALSA applications are treated like Pulseaudio applications. So when you use `arecord` or `audacity` (buth ALSA applications) with the default ALSA input, you are really using Pulseaudio (you could also use `parecord` to directly access Pulseaudio). But when you select `hw:XXX`, you are recording directly from the ALSA drivers.

Pulseaudio has its own (very flexible) concept of audio sources and sinks. You can see (and modify) which applications are connected to which sources and sinks using `pavucontrol` (and on many desktop environments, and similar desktop panel).

So if you run `arecord` and watch with `pavucontrol`, it should show up and record from the source belonging to the Intel HDA soundcard (usually "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo").

**Why does it record the sound that is playback at the same time?** One would have to look at the codec in more detail (you can do that with `cat /proc/asound/card*/codec\#*`), but there is a mixer control called "Loopback mixing" in your `amixer` output, and it is enabled. So I guess your codec contains a feature that allows you to record the sound that is currently output. Disable it in `alsamixer`, and see if anything changes.

**How do I set it up to automatically record from the Samson USB Mic?** You can configure the defaults in ALSA, but if you want to keep Pulseaudio, you should configure Pulseaudio instead. You can select audio sources per application in `pavucontrol` when the application is running, and Pulseaudio remembers the settings. You can also set the default audio source by clicking on "set as fallback" in the *Input* tab, or use `pacmd set-default-source my_source` from the commandline. `pacmd list-sources | grep name:` will give you a list of available sources. Drop the angular brackets when you use the source name on the commandline.

**Edit**

Each Pulseaudio sink has an associated `.monitor` source. So what's happening is that for some reason Pulseaudio can't get any ALSA input, so it can't make corresponding sources, so the only source that is left is the `.monitor` source, which happens to output the sound that is currently played back. So no internal loop in the codec (though this may *another* way to record currently played back sound).

Which means you have to debug why Pulseaudio can't create sources corresponding to ALSA inputs, though it creates a `dmix` sink, which it shouldn't, either - that should be a hardware sink.

Please provide the `/etc/asound.conf` and `~/.asoundrc` as first step. Before you start Pulseaudio, are there already programs running which use ALSA directly, and prevent Pulseaudio from using the hardware inputs/outputs?

Comment: Thank you for the response. So I opened `amixer` and turned off "Loopback mixing", however my playback audio was still being captured. Here is the output of `cat /proc/asound/card*/codec\#*`: https://pastebin.com/4t4B33kD. I also opened up `pavucontrol` and it only shows one input device, "Monitor of Built-in Audio". `pacmd list-sources | grep name:` also only outputs one source: "name: <alsa_output.dmix.monitor>". I can't change my input device / source to my microphone.

Comment: How can I tell if there is a program that uses ALSA directly before Pulseaudio starts? I don't think there are, but how can I be sure?

Comment: Good question. Best method I can think of is `lsof | grep /dev/snd`, that should show all processes using `/dev/snd/pcm*` (active I/O) or `/dev/snd/control*`.

Comment: Output of `lsof | grep /dev/sdn`: https://pastebin.com/ehfuku91